# Creating Spring Data Aggregation of multiple MongoDB queries

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

The database MongoDB I have stored documents in the format:

```
    {
      "achievement": [
        {
          "userFromId":"max",
          "userToId":"peter",
          "date":"2016-01-25",
          "pointCount":1,
          "description":"good work",
          "type":"THANKS"
        }
      ]
    }
```

How to get the number of records in the database (if any) for the a certain date, in which people are thanking the other people.
I created a query to retrieve data:

```
    DBObject clause1 = new BasicDBObject("userFromId", userFromId);
    DBObject clause2 = new BasicDBObject("userToId", userToId);
    DBObject clause3 = new BasicDBObject("sendDate", localDate);
    DBObject clause4 = new BasicDBObject("type", Thanks);
    BasicDBList or = new BasicDBList();
    or.add(clause1);
    or.add(clause2);
    or.add(clause3);
    or.add(clause4);
    DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("$or", or);
```

But I do not know how to get the number of records and how can rewrite the query using aggregation?
For example:

```
        Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
            Aggregation.group("userFromId")
                .first("userFromId").as("userFromId")
                .sum("pointCount").as("pointCount"));
```

I do not know how to add a few more parameters.
What the return request if the data to the database does not exist?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you add the expected output ? Why do you want to use the aggregation ?

Comment: I need to check true or false
I thought to make it through list
And then check whether there is data in the collection or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this. This will count all the number of documents matching the below criteria.

Regular Query

```
db.collection.count({ $or: [ { "userFromId": userFromId }, { "userToId": userToId } ] });
```

Using Aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
  { $match: { $or: [ { "userFromId": userFromId }, { "userToId": userToId } ] } },
  { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
] );
```

Comment: When you try to seek to aggregate query produces the error message: ReferenceError: userFromId not defined.
Tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `userFromId` and `userToId` are input values. Replace them with the input values. You should run the above queries in mongo shell.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's my fault.
Thank you for your patience

Comment: Don't worry. Happy to help.